# Cannot use jQuery to set form fields in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to access form fields in a Blog post list input form in Sharepoint 2010.  I uploaded jquery to the site's library and the form recognizes jQuery.  I can print out text and run my own simple functions (like printing the date), but I cannot access the form elements.  I have a column titled "MyColumn", and I am trying to access it this way:

```
$("input[title='MyColumn']").val("foobar");
```

This is what I have seen suggested on numerous forums and blog sites.  However, it has no effect.  The text field for `MyColumn` remains empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the input have an id = 'MyColumn'?, you typically do not select based on the title attribute

Comment: This is not enough information to get support. Can you plz post the full corresponding jQuery script.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to view the source to see what the generated fields id were called. Example to populate a query string value:

var myname = $.urlParam('name');
$('#ctl00_m_g_e256ce90_75de_4635_b4ba_69f8dd0c6e1b_ff51_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(myname);